# How do I sum the products of the elements of a vector?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, vector

I want to evaluate a sum like $\sum\limits_{j > i}^n q_i^k\, q_j^k$, where $n$ is the length of the vector $q^k$. The vector $q^k$ is, for example, $[q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4]$ and $i$ and $j$ correspond to the index of the vector elements.

This was my attempt; I got errors :/

[image]

Comment: Are the vectors large? Is the desired sum over subsets other than size 2 also? Are the vectors numeric? If so, there are considerably faster methods than those already posted.

Comment: I am using small test cases for now, but the length of each additional vector I try to analyze increases exponentially, so it can get large.  The Hamiltonian I am working with ought to be 2-local and the vectors are binary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
vec = Table[q[i], {i, 4}]
(* {q[1], q[2], q[3], q[4]} *)

With[{l = Length[vec]}, 
    Sum[vec[[i]] vec[[j]], {i, 1, l}, {j, i + 1, l}]
]
(* q[1] q[2] + q[1] q[3] + q[2] q[3] + q[1] q[4] + q[2] q[4] + q[3] q[4] *)

Plus @@ Times @@@ Subsets[vec, {2}]
(* q[1] q[2] + q[1] q[3] + q[2] q[3] + q[1] q[4] + q[2] q[4] + q[3] q[4] *)
```

**Update**

For binary vectors (see OP's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127121/how-do-i-sum-the-products-of-the-elements-of-a-vector#comment343873_127121)), a fast approach would be:

```
vec = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10^6];

Binomial[Total[vec], 2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0010, 124964252556} *)

(* comparison of the result with Jim Baldwin's answer *)
%[[2]] === (Total[vec^k]^2 - Total[vec^(2 k)])/2
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 11):

`SymmetricPolynomial` is the built-in way to get the sums you want:

```
vec = Table[q[i], {i, 4}];

SymmetricPolynomial[2, vec^k]
(* q[1]^k q[2]^k+q[1]^k q[3]^k+q[2]^k q[3]^k+q[1]^k q[4]^k+q[2]^k q[4]^k+q[3]^k q[4]^k *)
```

(But @Xavier 's way will help you understand Mathematica better.)

**Update**

To follow up on @ciao 's comment, if the values are numeric, then there are definitely better ways.  For your example, the following works:

```
n = 4000;
k = 2;
vec = Abs[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.2], n]];

Timing[(Total[vec^k]^2 - Total[vec^(2 k)])/2]
(* {0.`,8.583920493183017`*^6} *)

Timing[SymmetricPolynomial[2, vec^k]]
(* {2.6364169`,8.583920493183037`*^6} *)
```

Note the difference in timing.  The point is that one can determine such sums as you have using just using the sums of the powers of the vector elements.