# How to sum products of vector elements in a set of vectors?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, vector

Let $a$ be a set of vectors such that $a = \{q^2, q^3, q^4\, ...\}$, where $q^k$ is a vector of length $2^k$, and of the form $q^k = \{q[1], q[2], ..., q[k]\}.$ I want to evaluate a sum like $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{N-1} \sum\limits_{h>k}^N \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_k} q_{i}^k q_{i}^h$, where $n_k$ is the length of the vector $q^k$, and $N$ is the cardinality of $a$. This involves taking the product of components of vectors in seperate elements of the set. I made an attempt and got a nasty set of errors.

```
a = Array[q, 4]
b = Array[r, 8]
c = Array[s, 16]
z = {a, b, c}
OverlapV[v_] := 
Subscript[\[Lambda], overlap] Sum[With[{l = Length[v[[k]]]}, Sum[Sum[
  v[[k]][[i]] v[[h]][[i]], {i, 1, l}, {h, i + 1, Length[v]}], {h, 
  i + 1, Length[v]}]], {k, 1, Length[[v[k]]] - 1}]
```

[image]

I managed to accomplish something similar for the term $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{N} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n_k - 1} \sum\limits_{j > i}^{n_k} q_{i}^k q_{j}^k$ after some help in a similar posted question with this code:

```
One[x_] := With[{l = Length[x]},
Sum[Sum[x[[i]] x[[j]], {i, 1, l}, {j, i + 1, l}], {i, 1, l - 1}]]
OneV[v_] := 
Subscript[\[Lambda], one] Sum[F[v[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[v]}]
```

which gives the output:
[image]
 This is what I am trying to output for the first term. I am new to *Mathematica*, so I apologize if the code is messy or not idiomatic.

Comment: I don't understand your triple sum. Why don't you write down what you expect to get when `a, b, c` are smaller lists, e.g. of length `2, 3, 4`.

Comment: Sorry Xavier, had the wrong sum written for the second term.  Corrected.

Comment: `One` is wrong, unless you **really** want to sum twice over `i`; but the outer sum, where you have `{i, 1, l - 1}`, sums over an already summed expression with no iterator left, so it basically mulitplies it by `l-1`...

Comment: Also, I'm concerned about what you mean by $\sum_{j>i}^n a_j a_i$: that's a summation over only one index $j$ which must be greater than $i$, so e.g. when $i=4$, $j=5,6,\ldots,n-1,n$. You can **then** sum this over $i$. So I'm not sure whether the ansers to your [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127121/how-do-i-sum-the-products-of-the-elements-of-a-vector) really answer your needs.

Comment: Considering your `z`: you want to sum over `k` from 2 to $N−1=3-1=2$, so basically you're just setting `k=2`. Next, over $h>k=2$ up to $N=3$, so in fact $h=3$. So effectively you're summing over $i$ from 1 to $n_k=n_2=$`Length@b`$=8$. The output is `r[1] s[1] + r[2] s[2] + r[3] s[3] + r[4] s[4] + r[5] s[5] + r[6] s[6] + r[7] s[7] + r[8] s[8]`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) and [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html).

With

```
a = Indexed[q, #] & /@ Range[1, #] & /@ Range[1, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
Sum[a[[k, i]]*a[[h, i]], 
  {k, 2, Length[a] - 1}, 
  {h, k + 1, Length[a]}, 
  {i, 1, Length[a[[k]]]}]
```

or when entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+`sumt`+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

IMHO, the above bit of code demonstrates one of the best features of *Mathematica*: Your code can be written in mathematical notation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood what you wanted correctly, but it seems you wanted something like this:

```
a = Array[q, 4];
b = Array[r, 8];
c = Array[s, 16];
z = {a, b, c};

Total[Dot @@@ (PadRight[#, {2, Min[Length /@ #]}] & /@ Subsets[z, {2}])]
   q[1] r[1] + q[2] r[2] + q[3] r[3] + q[4] r[4] + q[1] s[1] + r[1] s[1] + q[2] s[2] +
   r[2] s[2] + q[3] s[3] + r[3] s[3] + q[4] s[4] + r[4] s[4] + r[5] s[5] + r[6] s[6] +
   r[7] s[7] + r[8] s[8]
```

As I understood it, you want all possible pairs of your vectors in $a$ (thus, `Subsets[]`), take the dot product of the members of each pair (with truncation as needed, hence `PadRight[]`), and then sum that all up.